# Get single document in express doesn't jumps to catch

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following express code. If I try to get a document with a non-existent id, I get nothing. The problem is that I get 200 as response status and I don't get the Failed message. The code jumps every time into "then".

```
const Mymodel = require('../model/Mymodel');

const Single = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Mymodel.findById(id)
    .then(result => {
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(404).send({"Failed": "Document not found"});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your finding query response is null so this is not an error. if you send res.status(404).send({"Failed": "Document not found"}); response for not found  use this.

```
const Mymodel = require('../model/Mymodel');

const Single = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Mymodel.findById(id)
    .then(result => {
      if(result){
       res.send(result);
      }else{
       res.status(404).send({"Failed": "Document not found"});
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(404).send({"Failed": "Document not found"});
    });
}
```